# Open Layers Bounding Box Size Restriction

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers-3, bounding-box

I would like to restrict the user in draw the bounding box to certain size, say 1024 x 1024.
How can I do this in Open Layers 3 (OL3)?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the bounding box of a feature being drawn should be restricted to 1024 x 1024 pixels? And, do yo want OpenLayers 2 or 3 -- they are very different. If 3, can you update your question with that tag?

Comment: Yes, that's the restriction I want in Open Layers 3 (OL3). I specified in the question, but not in the tag - I updated the tag as well.

Comment: I am interested to see what you have tried so far, seeing as regular polygon handling doesn't seem to have been added to OL3 yet.

Comment: Well, I am clueless too - hence posted. OL3 does support drawing polygons, but polygon handling - what do you mean? Like event handler. There is postcompose - but, not sure how to do this....

Comment: Lol, I wouldn't say clueless, exactly, but yes a lot has changed. If you look in OL2, you will see there is a RegularPolygon handler http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Handler/RegularPolygon.js that takes care of generating the actual points. This does not seem to exist yet in OL3, as an interaction, which appears to be what handlers have become.

Answer (score 0):

You may catch the drawend event and filter accordingly.

```
  drawInteraction.on("drawend", function(e) {
    var feature = e.target.sketchFeature_;
    // allow or disallow here, not sure how you can do that.
  });
```

drawInteraction is of type `ol.interaction.Draw`, your interaction geometry type `ol.geom.GeometryType` would be Polygon.

Comment: There is a ol.interaction.DragBox which is useful for automatically creating box. But, still clueless on how to restrict the size in something similar called boxend.